# How to use boost::algorithm::ends_with() for boost::asio::mutable_buffer and boost::asio::const_buffer iterator ranges?

Tags: boost

Consider this function:

```cpp
    std::size_t DoReadUntil(const boost::asio::mutable_buffer& buffer, const boost::asio::const_buffer& delim)
    {
        boost::system::error_code error;
        const boost::asio::mutable_buffer buffer_1(buffer.data(), 1);
        std::size_t ret = 0;

        for (;;)
        {
            boost::asio::read(m_serialPort, buffer_1, error);
            auto itRange1 = boost::make_iterator_range(boost::asio::buffer_sequence_begin(buffer), boost::asio::buffer_sequence_end(buffer));
            auto itRange2 = boost::make_iterator_range(boost::asio::buffer_sequence_begin(delim), boost::asio::buffer_sequence_end(delim));

            if (boost::algorithm::ends_with(itRange1, itRange2))
                break;
        }

        DoSetLastError(error);
        return ret;
    }
```

I am getting a compiler error at the call: `boost::algorithm::ends_with()` with the error message:
`C:\msys32\mingw32\include\boost\algorithm\string\compare.hpp|43|error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'const boost::asio::mutable_buffer' and 'const boost::asio::const_buffer')|`

What is my code problem here?

Is there a replacement for `boost::algorithm::ends_with()` I can try?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mutable_buffer` has `data()` member function which points to buffer of data. It also has `size` method to indicate the size of buffer.

You can use both to create range: `[ data(), data()+size() )`. `data()` returns `void*`, so you need to cast it to `char*`:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> v2{2,3};

    auto buffer = boost::asio::buffer(v);
    auto delim = boost::asio::buffer(v2);

    auto itRange1 = boost::make_iterator_range((char*)buffer.data(), (char*)buffer.data() + buffer.size());
    auto itRange2 = boost::make_iterator_range((char*)delim.data(), (char*)delim.data() + delim.size());
    if (boost::algorithm::ends_with(itRange1, itRange2)) {
        puts("true"); // printed on console
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ff9379308043299)

---

Your version doesn't work because `buffer_sequence_begin` for `mutable_buffer` returns `mutable_buffer*` - pointer. So you want to compare mutable_buffer instances, but they doesn't support comparison.

Comment: Indeed, your solution works. It is just that `buffer_sequence_begin` and `buffer_sequence_end` trolled me and are useless here.

Comment: Good answer.  I can't believe you wrote C-style re-interpret casts there though.I don't think that's a good idea, or even required. There's `buffer_cast<>` and you can even use the buffer iterators directly: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2919c5788bc17230

Comment: Alternative take using `buffer_cast` and `string_view::ends_with` for good measure: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42b1b2f080f7775d

Comment: @sehe, thank you for the clarification, but about `buffer_cast`, the documentation says it is deprecated and we should use the `data()` member function. And why should I use `buffers_begin` and `buffers_end` from your code instead of directly using `data()` and `data() + size()` ? TIA.

Comment: Didn't know about deprecation. The iterators again prevent you having to do ugly casting. Also, they are safe in the sense that they do not assume contiguous underlying storage (in Asio, buffers can be modeled by sequences of underlying buffers as well). Regardless of anything else, never write `(T) expr`. Always spell `static_cast<T>(expr)`, `const_cast<T>(expr)` or `reinterpret_cast<T>(expr)` to express what you intended.

Comment: @sehe You are right, this cast is ugly :) but in my defense I was in hurry :D I have never used `buffers_begin/end` before, nice. Always something new to learn.